# External display is the wrong size

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

Im trying to get a Dell p2414h 24 Inch monitor working with my MacbookPro 13 Inch. It appears that Ubuntu detects the wrong display size for my external monitor as the Screen Display menu shows the 24 Inch monitor around half the size of my 13Inch display.

The scaling results in any window dragged between the two screens to drastically change size to the point where my larger display is unusable because the windows are so large.

Xrandr appears to be reporting the correct screensize when I list the displays so I'm not sure what I need to configure to fix this. Do I need to fudge with DPI setting on my lower-res but larger display to get this to work properly?

[image]

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1600, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 179mm
   2560x1600     59.97*+
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 297mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: I had the same problem.The solution in both threads bellow solved the VLC problem, but the display size is still wrong in settings. VLC interface too big in 18.04:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390362
Huge client window on gnome shell:
https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-client/issues/809